# Using a GUI with a custom WSQLite3

Tags: sqlite

I am new to a position where my predecessor built a custom WSQLite3.exe/dll that allowed him to read in custom aggregate functions for common queries our organization does to minimize the need to write and rewrite the joins. They are read in from a .sql file

Because of this, I am relegated to work in the command line which I find very limiting since I need to copy/paste and browse the tables a lot.

Has anyone had success using a custom wsqlite3.exe build with one of the many SQLite 3 GUIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard `sqlite3.exe` shell (and most programs based on it) have the `.load` command to load extensions that are designed for this purpose.
This is probably not the case for your extension.

Many GUIs have no extension mechanism, or support the same extension format.
The [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) Firefox extension supports extensions written in JavaScript.